# intention.js render html adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use [Intention.js](http://ahmadassaf.com/blog/web-development/scripts-plugins/intention-js-manipulate-dom-via-html-attributes-responsive-layouts/).

When using intention.js, how would one render a page differently as based on screen width
Intention.js has code to adjust page rendering based on devices as shown in code sample below

```
<html> <header>
<img src="logo.png" intent
  in-highres-src="retina.png" />
</header>

<nav intent
 in-mobile-prepend="#content"
 in-tablet-prepend="#content"
 in-standard-after="header"
 in-touch-class="swipeDrawer">

<a id="about" intent
 in-mobile-href="about.html"
 in-tablet-href="about.html"
 in-standard-href="#about">About</a>
<a id="projects" href="/faq"
 intent
 in-mobile-before="#about">FAQ</a>
</nav>

<div id="content" intent
 in-width: in-orientation:>
 This is all so complex
</div>
</html>
```

However it is not clear to me how it is decided what a specific screen size is.

What is mobile / tablet / standard? I believe it is possible to determine the width and show content based on that using intention.js, but how to define such widths using this library is unclear to me.

And, given that information how would one render different tables based on those specific sizes?

I guess something like:

```
<table intent
   in-tablet-td
   in-mobile-td      <<-- but wouldnt that change only a single td  ?
```

I'm looking for something that would define a table makeup like 3 columns or 5 depending on screen size.

**//-------------------update 14nov2013------------------**

I think i am onto something
It seams that the values of screen width are set in another script.
Besides intention.js there is a script required called context.js
in there i read:

```
  intent.responsive([{name:'base'}]).respond('base');

// width context?
// =======================================================================
horizontal_axis = intent.responsive({
  ID:'width',
  contexts: [
    {name:'standard', min:840}, 
    {name:'tablet', min:510},
    {name:'mobile', min:0}],
  // compare the return value of the callback to each context
  // return true for a match
  matcher: function(test, context){
    if(typeof test === 'string'){

      return test === context.name;
    }
    return test>=context.min;
  },
  // callback, return value is passed to matcher()
  // to compare against current context
```

So here not only i find the names "standard / tablet /..." but they are as well defined here?
Apperantly those variables are created here, they are not inside intention.js

Now i am only left to findout, how to do the different table makeups.

Comment: Post your attempts. We need to see your code.

Comment: its pretty hard as i dont know how to retrieve those screen widths 
If i knew how then i wouldnt ask this question, but i rewrote the entire question, so maybe then its more clear for what i am after. While the framework is kinda new and not many people are using it.

As i'm not a JS expert its realy hard to show code samples that are not working because JS isnt my normal language, how to explain green to someone who is color blind ? but he still has to ask what is green to pass the traffic lights, i feel like i'm into such question. the framework isnt that well documented on this part.